# Vertical scrolling lags on Appcelerator titanium

Tags: ios, scroll, titanium, appcelerator

```
App.UI.Views.SingleInformationWindow = function() {
var _ = require("../libs/underscore")._;

    var that = this;

    var defaults = App.Defaults.SingleInformationWindow;

    var windowProperties = _.extend({}, defaults.Window);
    var scrollViewProperties = _.extend({}, defaults.ScrollView);
    var richTextViewProperties = _.extend({}, defaults.RichTextView);

    this.window = Ti.UI.createWindow(windowProperties);
    this.scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView(scrollViewProperties);
    this.richTextView = new App.UI.Views.RichTextView(richTextViewProperties);

    this.scrollView.add(this.richTextView.view);

    this.window.add(this.scrollView);

    this.overlay = Ti.UI.createView({zIndex: 100, backgroundColor: 'white'});
    this.window.add(this.overlay);

    this.window.addEventListener('postlayout', function() {
        that.window.remove(that.overlay);
    });

};
```

I'm working with appcelerator titanium sdk 9.0.3 to build ios app and I'm having a problem in such pages, when scrolling it scrolls back by itself, not all pages, the weird part that they're using same page view and the logs don't show any issue. any ideas on that ?
ps : I'm using scrollView

Comment: it is a very broad question. Some code or more information about the content of the `scrollView` would be nice. Are you sure you are using a `ScrollView` and not a `ScrollableView` since you are talking about pages? Are any events attached? Scrolling back sounds like an event is fired. Also please add the SDK version you are using. Build multiple apps with `ScrollableViews` and a lot of content and didn't have any issues, especially on the iOS side

Comment: if  you want people to help you gotta show some code. At least mention what UI component you're using, how you populate the data, how big the content is, how you're monitoring scroll in logs, etc.

Comment: sorry I just edited my post

Comment: @miga do you think that the listener used on this view is the main cause?

Comment: if you are talking about the `postlayout` listener on the window: shouldn't be a problem. Add a log and you'll see that it won't fire on every scroll. You could still remove it so it won't fire when you e.g. change the orientation. All this information is not enough to identify the issue. If I use this code (and change richtextview to a normal view) it's working fine. It could be the content, richTextView (whatever this is), the custom parameters, different listeners,...I even don't exactly understand the problem since it is a UI thing and not an error message. So we would need some visuals